# Implementing a CSS Reset in GatsbyJS

Tags: gatsby

I'm new to GatsbyJS and have been combing the documentation for a solution, but can't seem to find one, which makes me think that I'm missing some larger piece. I assumed the way to eliminate browser-default styling would be to import some sort of a `css-reset.css` file in my index layout and overwrite it with my own styles, along these lines:

```
import React from 'react';

import reset from './reset.module.css';
import styles from './index.module.css';
```

but I can't seem to overwrite them this way (only the reset is implemented). Is there something fundamental about GatsbyJS's build process that I'm missing here? Something I need to integrate into the `gatsby-config` file? Is there a plugin that does this/a better means of achieving the CSS reset? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to importing CSS Modules, you can simply import `css-reset.css` as you first described.

Following the example of the default Gatsby starter, you can place your stylesheets in `/layouts` and then import them in `/layouts/index.js` like this:

```
import ./reset.css
import ./index.css
```

This will apply your styles globally for you.

Another option with Gatsby is to use [Typography.js](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typography.js) and apply your global reset styles via the [overrideStyles](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typography.js#api) setting.

Answer (score 5):

You can import a reset/normalize/other global css imports using `gatsby-browser.js`. If you have a layout component for consistent theme, you can also import it there as well.

Do this to just include the stylesheet:

```
import '../styles/myGlobalStyle.css';
```

There's no need to assign the import to a variable, so **do not** do this:

```
import globalStyles from '../styles/myGlobalStyle.css';
```

For instance, using [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) in `gatsby-browser.js` (v2):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from './src/components/Context';

// This next line is all you need to import global styles
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  const ConnectedRootElement = <Provider>{element}</Provider>;
  return ConnectedRootElement;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

When using the plugin [typography.js](https://kyleamathews.github.io/typography.js/), normalize.css is included by default. Though I guess technically not a pure reset, you can further modify the base styles through the configuration object passed to the Typography instance.

Some of the options include: **baseFontSize, baseLineHeight, scaleRatio, blockMarginBottom, bodyWeight, headerWeight, overrideStyles.**

For example, this is what I use to set the font-size to 62.5%:

`const typography = new Typography({ baseFontSize: '10px' })`

You can read more about installing and setting up typography.js in the [part 2 of the official Gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/).

Answer (score 2):

When you import [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), you need to apply its classes to your components e.g.

```
import styles from 'my-styles.module.css'

export default () => <div className={styles.mainDiv}>Hi</div>
```

Comment: Does that imply that there's no way to apply stylesheets in full, like a CSS reset?

Comment: @kqcef, why you import CSS reset as a module in the first place? You can always add your CSS reset into `head` by importing it into index.js just like [default starter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/ee997d20aa4e42dfbf04183a42f247ac6d46b171/src/layouts/index.js#L6) do.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple : in gatsby-browser.js

```js
import("./src/css/normalize.css");
```

Then style your components via

```js
import 'myComponentStyles' from '../css/myComponent.module.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Material UI in combination with Gatsby you should use [CSS Baseline](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/). It does the same as `normalize.css`

```
import React from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      {/* The rest of your application */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```